# How to call a function of a particular object in a HashSet

Tags: java, oop, directory, hashset

I apologize if this has been answered already. I have done multiple searches and although I can find similar questions I can't find one the fully answers my question.

I'm writing a program in Java to help me manage files and folders on my computer.

I have written some code that creates a directory object. It then adds that object to a HashSet. (I use the HashSet to prevent the adding of duplicate directory Objects)

I now have the need to be able to access a particular object and execute some of that object's methods, however, I cant seem to find an effective way of doing that.

If someone could tell me how they would go about this process I'd be very grateful thanks!

Comment: Did you consider using a `HashMap` instead of a `HashSet`?  The key to the `HashMap` would be whatever you use to identify a directory.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Jerome! If you could tell us what you've already tried, and include the relevant code that's not working, it would help us address your need directly instead of guessing -- or more likely just ignoring the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It would really help if you could post your code, for context. I'd also consider using a Set or HashMap instead of a HashSet, but that's all personal preference. Now, onto the question. I'm not sure what's going on in your code, but if you want to call multiple methods on an object in a HashSet, extract the object's data from the HashSet by calling its index and then store it as an object. Then, call all the methods you need.

Comment: Sorry - just a quick revision. Since I realized HashSet has no .get(), you'd have to iterate over it with a for-each loop, and then store the object that matched what you're looking for in a prexistent object instantiated beforehand.